# Lodash findWhere with Object as value of key

Tags: lodash

I have a list of objects and i am trying to use underscore findwhere function to find an object in the list with a key and another objects as its value. I have tried doing this but get an undefined value. So my question is underscore findwhere available to find objects with a key that has a value of another object, rather than a string or number. Sample code.

```
var a = [
  {channel: {aa: "1", bb: "2"}, id: 233332},
  {channel: {aa: "3", bb: "4"}, id: 822211}
]

var b = {channel: {aa: "1", bb: "2"}, id: 233332}
```

_.findWhere(a, b) should return {channel: {aa: "1", bb: "2"}, id: 233332} which it does for this array of objects with two keys but with a more populated object i.e one that has more keys and values it doesn't seem to work, are there any gotchas with findWhere or any things i didn't consider?

Comment: So lodash or underscore ? because they are different in some cases.

Comment: its lodash version 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .findWhere method matches all properties from object b. If you add extra properties, the match will fail. What you can do however is the following:

```
_.findWhere(a, _.pick(b, ['channel', 'id']));
```

The _.pick will create a new object, with only those key/value pairs that are also available in your array a.

Answer (score 7):

_.findWhere is deprecated in lodash v4.0.0, so it's better to use _.find with _.matches.

[lodash _.matches](https://lodash.com/docs#matches)

```
var a = [
  {channel: {aa: "3", bb: "4"}, id: 822211},
  {channel: {aa: "1", bb: "2"}, id: 233332}
];

var b = {channel: {aa: "1", bb: "2"}, id: 233332, desc:"Hello"};
_.find(a, function(n){
    if(_.matches(n)(b)){
       return n;
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle with lodash v3.1.0](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulchaturvedie/9s32ubb2/12/)

Now if you want other way around

```
var a = [
  {channel: {aa: "3", bb: "4"}, id: 822211, desc:"Hello"},
  {channel: {aa: "1", bb: "2"}, id: 233332, desc:"Hello"}
];

var b = {channel: {aa: "1", bb: "2"}, id: 233332};
_.find(a, function(n){
    if(_.matches(b)(n)){
       return n;
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle with lodash v3.1.0](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulchaturvedie/o2n38ro6/1/)